# What's the difference between starting a service by "/etc/init.d/noip2 start" and Starting it directly from /usr/local/bin?

Tags: command, daemon, sysvinit

I'm curious since if you look at an Init.d script, The content just seems to be "start this program located in this directory".

Is there any difference between The two commands (I'm not talk ing about runlevels but running them  manually)?

Thanks!